# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 gradle

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

flutter run gradle error please help me

gradle error i cant use emulator

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361482/gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-because-could-not-find-or-l